# Ubuntu 15.10 randomly crashing back to login screen

Tags: unity, login-screen, intel, crash, 15.10

fresh install of Ubuntu 15.10 here.
Everything works fine, but I'm getting random crashes back to the login screen.

I pasted my syslog here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12989589/

Edit: Confirmed bug on intel video driver + compiz with windows animations enabled. Workaround:

- Edit or create: /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
- Add the following:

  ```
  Section "Device"
   Identifier "Card0"
   Driver "Intel"
   Option "AccelMethod" "uxa"
  EndSection
  ```

This disables "sna" acceleration, and uses "uxa" instead (the old one)

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1509846

Comment: Paste also `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.

Comment: I just had the same behavior when clicking on print button on LibreOffice Impress.
Here is the log of /var/log/Xorg.0.log.old: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12997549/

Comment: Related?: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1510970

Comment: looks like your X is crashing with Intel driver. You need to file a bug in launchpad.

Comment: Yeah, pretty much: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1509846

Comment: Workaround while the issue is fixed:

- Edit or create:
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf

- Add the following:

Section "Device"
 Identifier "Card0"
 Driver "Intel"
 Option "AccelMethod" "uxa"
EndSection


This disables "sna" acceleration, and uses "uxa" instead (the old one)

Comment: Grandfather Clause, leave open or close all old questions. This question has 17 upvotes and four answers.

Answer (score 0):

I had strange issue when using mentioned workaround by disabling "sna"  acceleration. Top 1px of the display started flashing randomly, with variations in intensity and only visible on black themes, like Ambiance.

Tried 4.2.8-040208-generic #201512150620 SMP kernel from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ as suggested in one of the answers: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1509846/comments/35  and it seems to work OK. Sna is enabled and Xorg doesn't crash when creating new windows. It previously crashed whenever I clicked "New incognito window" in chromium. And also no flashing 1px at the top.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying the driver from Intel?
[Intel Graphics Linux Driver](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads)

Install the download through Software Center, then run the installer in terminal as root.

Comment: Same issue, this seems to fix it. I'm still getting a crash every now and then when I press ctrl-t to make a new tab in Chrome, but not that often.

Answer (score 0):

Go to terminal

sudo su

software-properties-gtk

go to additional drivers tab

check whether graphics drivers are properly installed or not

if not install them

Answer (score 0):

You have misconfigured or messedup with xorg while tweaking your system

**Solution:**

Try to enter with someother user Like Guest if, Yes then Logout guest and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to enter your Terminal mode.

Login with your user which has sudo powers
Create a new user and add this user to sudo group

```
sudo adduser username
sudo adduser username sudo
```

now logout and login with newly created sudo user and delete your messedup user. That's it.

**Other solution:**

Install other GUI for system i.e Gnome
Goto terminal mode by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

```
install gnome
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
```

This will install gnome 3, gnome classic and gnome-classic without effects to enter gnome on your login screen press unity icon and you will see the list of interfaces to choose from.

HOPE this will help

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but your response have nothing to do with the problem. Look at the links I posted.